# Looping a button and having items inside iterate over an array

Tags: java, android

I have a fashcard program and I'm trying to have it use the same activity, button and text box for all the flashcards in the program. What I'm trying to do is have the program iterate over two arrays for the front side of the flashcard and for the text inserted by the user.

*These are the errors I get with the following code*

- Line breakpoint:Flashcards1 [line: 54] - onClick(View)

  - Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different 
    method

int i=0;

```
    while ( i<10 ) {
    //clicking submit button, checking if strings are equal, and then if correct moving onto next 
        //items in arrays
    enterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View view) {

                i++;

                flashCardWord.setText(otherWord[i]);

                if (englishWord[i].equals(inputAnswer.getText().toString()) )

                {   

                    feedback.setText("correct");
                    flashCardWord.setText(otherWord[i]);


                    }





        }});}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your `int i=0;` inside your inner class.

Comment: The problem is that if I include int = 0; in the inner class it occurs after the first instance of the variable (while ( i<10 )). I'm trying to loop the button and have it iterate over my arrays each time it's clicked on

Comment: I can't give you a better answer if you are not providing any more information e.g. your whole class, the whole error log etc.